# Что такое файл подкачки, зачем он нужен и где используется?

Tags: ос, хранение-данных, файл-подкачки

Я видел на одном сайте, что "если бы все приложения в системе освобождали неиспользуемую память, только после её заполнения, интенсивное использование файла подкачки сделало бы работу просто невозможной.".
Вот список вопросов:

1. Что такое файл подкачки?
2. Зачем нужен?
3. Где применяется?
4. Почему это "сделало бы работу просто невозможной"?
5. На что повлияло бы то, что это "сделало бы работу просто невозможной"? Работу приложения?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: Один запрос в гугл -- "*`файл подкачки`*" сразу выводит на [Что такое файл подкачки — принцип работы и положение](https://sonikelf.ru/tochechnaya-optimizaciya-chast-1-fajl-podkachki/) / Думаю, после прочтения список вопросов уменьшится минимум вдвое

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что такое файл подкачки?

Это такой способ расширения оперативной памяти компьютера.

> Зачем нужен?

Приложения любят пользоваться оперативной памятью, но при этом, хотя они её "захватывают" часто эти приложения могут быть не активны в данный момент. При этом памяти может не хватать другим приложениям. Поэтому операционная система может делать вид, что у неё есть, например, в 2 раза больше оперативной памяти, чем на самом деле. При этом она загружает память приложений в оперативную память с диска, если эта память нужна активным в данный момент приложениям, или наоборот выгружает память приложений из оперативной памяти на диск, если эти приложения в данный момент не очень активны.

> Где применяется?

Практически все операционные системы используют файл подкачки.

> Почему это "сделало бы работу просто невозможной"?

Потому что операционная система только и делала бы, что загружала/выгружала данные на диск из оперативной памяти, а диск, как известно, работает на порядки медленнее, чем оперативная память.

> На что повлияло бы то, что это "сделало бы работу просто невозможной"? Работу приложения?

На работу всех приложений, всего, что крутится на данном компьютере в целом. Приложения станут работать очень медленно, будут медленно реагировать даже на нажатия клавиш и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Файл подкачки нужен на компьютерах с малым количеством оперативной памяти, и дополняет ее. Хоть его скорость намоного меньше обычной оперативной памяти, приложения не будут просто закрываться от нехватки оперативы.

Последние два пункта я не понял.

Comment: Не только с малым количеством памяти такое нужно. Самой ОС тоже бывает нужна память под кэши там всякие и т.д. Да и некоторым приложениям полезно бывает дать побольше памяти даже в ущерб другим приложениями. Поэтому всегда полезно иметь такой механизм, который позволяет освободить часть оперативки под какие-то нужды ОС или приложений.